# CMD - Check if exist firewall rule, and add if not

Tags: windows, firewall, scripting, windows-command-prompt

I need some help to make an script that check if exist a rule, and add if not.
It auto add all exe inside a folder where i run it.

```
@echo off
cls

Echo.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOR /r %%G in ("*.exe") Do (

netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all | find "Nombre de regla:" | find "%%G" > nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (
@echo Added - %%G
NETSH advfirewall firewall add rule name="%%G" dir=in program="%%G" action="block" enable="yes" > nul
NETSH advfirewall firewall add rule name="%%G" dir=out program="%%G" action="block" enable="yes" > nul
) else ( 
@echo Exist- %%G 
)
)

Echo.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Echo.
Echo End.
Echo.
pause
```

What I doing wrong? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest using PowerShell. There is a specific set of cmdlets for managing Windows Firewall, and it's a lot better environment for scripting.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/get-netfirewallrule
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/set-netfirewallrule
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/remove-netfirewallrule

Comment: the problem is that it has to run in win7 too, some version not have PS :(